# How to disable the options in jquery chosen page load event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

Hi I am developing jquery application. I have one dropdownlistbox with jquery chosen. Whenever I load my page first time by default I want to hide some of the options in dropdown. For example, Below is my dropdownlistbox,

```
<select class="limitedNumbSelect2" multiple="true">
        <option value="1">Monday</option>
        <option value="2">Tuesday</option>
        <option value="3">Wednesday</option>
        <option value="4">Thursday</option>
        <option value="5">Friday</option>
        <option value="6">Saturday</option>
        <option value="6">Sunday</option>
    </select>
```

This is my java script code.

```
 $(function () {
        $(".chosen-select").chosen();
    });
  $(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('.limitedNumbSelect2 li:contains("Monday")').hide();
    });
```

The above code does not work as expected. It does not hide Monday on page load. May I get some help here? Thank you all.

Comment: there's no element with class `chosen-select`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix this you can remove the required `option` element *before* you instantiate the Chosen library on the `select`, like this:

```js
$(function() {
    $(".limitedNumbSelect2").find('option:contains("Monday")').remove().end().chosen();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.6.2/chosen.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.6.2/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="limitedNumbSelect2" multiple="true">
  <option value="1">Monday</option>
  <option value="2">Tuesday</option>
  <option value="3">Wednesday</option>
  <option value="4">Thursday</option>
  <option value="5">Friday</option>
  <option value="6">Saturday</option>
  <option value="6">Sunday</option>
</select>
```

Alternatively if you have no alternative but to amend the `option` elements *after* calling `chosen()`, then you can use the `chosen:updated` event to manually update the shown options:

```js
$(function() {
    var $chosen = $(".limitedNumbSelect2").chosen();
  
    // your other code here...
  
    $chosen.find('option:contains("Monday")').remove();
    $chosen.trigger("chosen:updated"); 
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.6.2/chosen.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.6.2/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="limitedNumbSelect2" multiple="true">
  <option value="1">Monday</option>
  <option value="2">Tuesday</option>
  <option value="3">Wednesday</option>
  <option value="4">Thursday</option>
  <option value="5">Friday</option>
  <option value="6">Saturday</option>
  <option value="6">Sunday</option>
</select>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help. I updated the answer to cover updating the options after the Chosen has been loaded too

Comment: For example if i have some values in array and i want to hide those values in dropdown I am trying as below.  $.each(users11, function (index, value) {
                $(".limitedNumbSelect").find('option:contains(this.value)').prop('disabled', true).end().chosen();
                        });
        }); but it is not working. this.val is not the right way to put here?

Comment: I'd start a new question for that as it's a completely different issue to this one

Answer (score 1):

I think that the better way is by hiding options by its value and not by its text.

So, you can write:

```
$('.limitedNumbSelect2 option[value="1"]').hide();
```

In your code you mention 'li' element that is not present at all...

Comment: Thank you. For example if i have array and loop through array and hide the options   $.each(users11, function (index, value) {
                $('.limitedNumbSelect2 option[value="?"]').hide();
                        });
        }); May I know what i can put in place of question mark?

Comment: When you use $.each() you can refer every item inside the loop using $(this)
Alternatively, you can use 'index' and 'value' (parameters of function). So, instead of the question mark you should write:
$('.limitedNumbSelect2 option[value="' + value + '"]').hide(); }); });
Using 'value' variable to construct the selection string.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code:

```
jQuery('.limitedNumbSelect2 option:contains("Monday")').hide();
```